# How do I add a reaction emoji to the message the bot sends after doing the user's command?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I get this error: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'message'--when trying to do `await self.client.message.add_reaction(emoji)`.

I tried changing it to `await ctx.message.add_reaction(emoji)`, and I realized that it reacted to the command the user sent rather than the bot's new message.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class MovieNight(commands.Cog):
    """Polls for Movie Night."""

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command(aliases=['m'])
    async def movie(self, ctx, year, *movie):
        movie_title = ' '.join(movie[:-1])
        await ctx.send(f"`{year}` - `{movie_title}` | **{movie[-1]}**")
        emoji = ''
        await self.client.message.add_reaction(emoji)

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(MovieNight(client))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding onto Patrick's answer here from what you said in the comment.

`await self.client.message.add_reaction(emoji)` won't work because the bot doesn't know what message you're referring to, and `client` doesn't have an attribute called `message`.

Adding reactions requires a `discord.Message` object, which in your case can be either the command that the user executed (e.g. `!movie 2020 movie title`) which you can retrieve via `ctx.message`, or a message which you're making the bot send.

If you wanted to get the message object from the message that the bot sent, you can assign it to a variable:

```py
msg = await ctx.send(f"`{year}` - `{movie_title}` | **{movie[-1]}**")
```

And this allows you to then add a reaction to it or access any other message attributes you would like:

```py
emoji = ''
await msg.add_reaction(emoji)
```

---

**References:**

- [`discord.Message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message)
- [`Message.add_reaction()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.add_reaction)
- [`TextChannel.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.send) - Here you can see it returns the message that was sent

Comment: Great job at sorting it out by yourself, glad to hear it! Good luck with the bot :^)

Answer (score 2):

`self.client` doesn't know about the message, the is stored as part of the [invocation context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#invocation-context):

```
await ctx.message.add_reaction(emoji)
```

Comment: "the is stored"? I don't understand what was said here. But, I'm not sure at all how to go about doing what I want now: how would I even fetch the bot's new message?